# How to find the average of a split float list from a text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code:

```
chosen_year = int(input("Enter the year of interest: "))
print("")

min_life_exp = 999.9
max_life_exp = -1.1
min_life_entity = ""
max_life_entity = ""
min_year = 9999
max_year = -1

chosen_min_life_exp = 999.9
chosen_max_life_exp = -1.1
chosen_min_life_entity = ""
chosen_max_life_entity = ""

with open("life-expectancy.csv") as life_file:

    for line in life_file:
        parts = line.split(",")

        entity = parts[0]
        code = parts[1]
        year = int(parts[2])
        life_exp = float(parts[3])

        if max_life_exp < life_exp:
            max_life_exp = life_exp
            max_life_entity = entity
            max_year = year
        
        if min_life_exp > life_exp:
            min_life_exp = life_exp
            min_life_entity = entity
            min_year = year

        if chosen_year == year:

            avg_life_exp = sum(life_exp) / len(life_exp)

            if chosen_max_life_exp < life_exp:
                chosen_max_life_exp = life_exp
                chosen_max_life_entity = entity 
        
            if chosen_min_life_exp > life_exp:
                chosen_min_life_exp = life_exp
                chosen_min_life_entity = entity

print(f"The overall max life expectancy is: {max_life_exp} from {max_life_entity} in {max_year}")
print(f"The overall max life expectancy is: {min_life_exp} from {min_life_entity} in {min_year}")
print("")
print(f"For the year {chosen_year}:")
print(f"The average life expectancy across all countries was {avg_life_exp:.2f}")
print(f"The max life expectancy was in {chosen_max_life_entity} with {chosen_max_life_exp}")
print(f"The max life expectancy was in {chosen_min_life_entity} with {chosen_min_life_exp}")
```

I get this error when I run it:

```
line 38, in <module>
    avg_life_exp = sum(life_exp) / len(life_exp)
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

how do I change my avg_life_exp to get an average of the life expectancies in the year the user asks for?

Comment: As the error suggests, you are treating ```life_exp``` as if it was an iterable. If ```life_exp``` is just a value you have nothing to sum.

Comment: you're iterating over lines, whenever you split "," you get the values of that line... sum() expects to receive an iterable, but you're passing a float instead.

Comment: i would recommend you try out pandas for this. Much easier and quicker to solve it

Answer (score 0):

To fix this current error, you just need to remove the sum() function Since life_exp is a currently a float. However, I’m guessing you want all of the life_exp in a list, then get the sum of them. To fo this, have the “sum” chunk of the code after reading the lines from the file, since you want to add everything up /after/ you get all the life_exp in each line in the list. If you’d like more specifics, please clarify your question and the expected output.

Comment: I am trying to get all of the life expectancies of each country of a certain year. basically I want the list that I have it equal to (parts[3]) and I want to add all of those up in the chosen_year that the user inputs.